# Don't understand output from collect()

Tags: java

How can I understand the output of this program? When I execute the below program, I see the below output but unable to understand what it is. It is the output from `collect()`:

```
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class example1 {
public static void main(String []args){
    List <Integer> list = Arrays.asList(new Integer []{3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
    HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = 
list.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(i->i%2 == 0?1:2));   /* what's problem here */
    System.out.println(map.get(0));
          }
     }
```

output

```
java: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds equality constraints: 
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap<java.lang.Integer,java.util.List<java.lang. Integer>> upper bounds: 
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<java.lang.Integer,java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>,java.lang.Object
```

Comment: Please show some effort.

Comment: What happens if you open this up in an IDE? Hint: is HashMap appropriate here?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have the wrong type declared for the return type of groupingByConcurrent. Change your declaration from

```
HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map
```

to

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, I conceptually prefer to use "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap".